# Regex in sscanf with length limitation

Tags: c, regex

I tried the following code to read number from a string to another string using regex

```
char des[25]={0};
char *src="1234567890";
sscanf(src, "%[[0-9]{1,5}]s", des);
sscanf(src, "%[^[0-9]{1,5}$]s", des);
```

I want only the first 5 digits. I'm not getting the desired output in either sscanf.

Comment: You have to learn that [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) doesn't have a general regular expression format. There is a single format that *resembles* a specific kind of regex, but it *isn't* a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the first 5 digits from `src` to `des`

```
#include <stdio.h>    

main() {
    char des[25]={0};
    char *src="1234567890";
    sscanf(src, "%5s\0", des);
    puts(des);
}
```

To read just numbers, replace the `sscanf` with:

```
sscanf(src, "%5[0-9]", des);
```